# Not able to return price detail in quote using CoinMarketCap api endpoint '/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest' in google appscript

Tags: api, google-apps-script, coinmarketcap

I'm using google appscript to try and retrieve the price details for individual currencies using CoinMarketCap api quotes endpoint as opposed to the listing that fetches 5000 pairs at a time, lest I dry out my api credits for the month in less than a week. But for some reason the quote returned is

> quote: { USD: [Object] } }

To give an excerpt of the returned JSON:

```
{ BTC: 
   { id: 1,
     name: 'Bitcoin',
     symbol: 'BTC',
     slug: 'bitcoin',
     num_market_pairs: 9466,
     date_added: '2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z',
     tags: 
      [ 'mineable',
        'pow',
        'sha-256',
....
....
     self_reported_circulating_supply: null,
     self_reported_market_cap: null,
     last_updated: '2022-05-27T04:37:00.000Z',
     quote: { USD: [Object] } },
```

How can I retrieve the actual quote figure for my currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [API Documentation](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest), the `quote` structure is:

```
"quote": {
  "USD": {
    "price": 6602.60701122,
    "volume_24h": 4314444687.5194,
    "volume_change_24h": -0.152774,
    "percent_change_1h": 0.988615,
    "percent_change_24h": 4.37185,
    "percent_change_7d": -12.1352,
    "percent_change_30d": -12.1352,
    "market_cap": 852164659250.2758,
    "market_cap_dominance": 51,
    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,
    "last_updated": "2018-08-09T21:56:28.000Z"
  }
}
```

A useful method to log objects effectively is:

```
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(theObject))
```

**Additionally:**

```
const key = `...`
const url = `...`
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: { 
    "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": key 
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true,
}

const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText()
const coinData = Object.entries(JSON.parse(response).data)

for (let [coin, data] of coinData) {
  Logger.log(`${coin}: ${data.quote.USD.price}`)
}
```

By converting the `data` object into an array, you can iterate/loop the data as shown above.

**Learn More:**

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Thanks @NEWAZA. Perhaps it was my inexperience showing up. I found a way to get the prices following your thought:
var url= 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC,ETH';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var data = response.getContentText()
  var json = JSON.parse(data)
  Logger.log(json["data"]["BTC"]["quote"]["USD"]["price"])
  Logger.log(json["data"]["ETH"]["quote"]["USD"]["price"])

Only thing is I need to get the price for each currency by naming it. There should be a more elegant way, but works for now.

Comment: @GaneshRaj Updated my post for you!